# Scipy: Speeding Up Sampling

Tags: performance, numpy, random, scipy, scipy.stats

I have developed the following program for generating a list of subsamples, in chunks, for a specific task. It is, however, very slow, since I am doing random samples in a loop.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

#GENERATE SOME RANDOMLY CHUNKED COUNT DATA
N_chunks=250
idx_chunks = np.random.randint(20, size=N_chunks)
idx_cumsum = np.cumsum(idx_chunks)
data_sample = stats.poisson(mu=5).rvs(size=np.sum(idx_chunks))
data_sample_split = np.split(data_sample, idx_cumsum)[:-1]

#GENERATE SUBSAMPLES OF THE LENGTH GIVEN BY EACH ELEMENT OF THE LIST
f = stats.poisson(mu=2)
output = []
total = 0
for _i1 in data_sample_split:
    temp = []
    for _ii1 in _i1:
        temp.append(f.rvs(_ii1))
    output.append(temp)
```

Is there a way I can I speed up the program, while obtaining exactly the same output?

I am specifically looking to presample all the samples I need, before reshaping to the list of lists. However, I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Most of the time (>95%) is spent in `f.rvs`. So there is not much you can do. If it is statistically fine to use multiple stats.poisson object to generate parts of the result, then you can use parallelism to speed up the process (using multiprocessing). Otherwise, only micro-optimizations using a low-level language could possibly help (ie rewriting `rvs` in C/C++) in this case (typically vectorization).

Comment: I was thinking of somehow generating the required number of samples and splitting it, which tends to be much faster. However, np.split only works for one level: I would need to do two levels of splitting, and I am not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming generating many value with `f.rvs` is equivalent to generating parts with `f.rvs`, then you can **generate a big array and split it yourself**. Here is an example:

```py
# [...] -- Same code than above

def advancedSplit(rawData, data_sample_split):
    output = []
    partialSum = 0
    for _i1 in data_sample_split:
        temp = []
        for _ii1 in _i1:
            temp.append(rawData[partialSum:partialSum+_ii1])
            partialSum += _ii1
        output.append(temp)
    return output

def generateSubsamples(data_sample_split):
    total = sum(map(sum, data_sample_split))
    rawData = f.rvs(total) # Generate a big array to be split
    return advancedSplit(rawData, data_sample_split) # Split the array efficiently

# GENERATE SUBSAMPLES OF THE LENGTH GIVEN BY EACH ELEMENT OF THE LIST
output = generateSubsamples(data_sample_split)
```

This is **50 times faster** than the original code on my machine.

---

You can also use the same logic as in the original code to split the source array with `np.split`. But in practice, this method is significantly slower (due do many small array allocations while the above code use cheap slices).

```py
def advancedSplitVect(rawData, data_sample_split):
    output = []
    partial_sum = 0
    for _i1 in data_sample_split:
        if len(_i1) > 0:
            idx_cumsum = np.cumsum(_i1)
            total = idx_cumsum[-1]
            temp = np.split(rawData[partial_sum:partial_sum+total], idx_cumsum[:-1])
            partial_sum += total
            output.append(temp)
        else:
            output.append([])
    return output
```

Note that `advancedSplit` can be optimized with the **Numba JIT** to slightly speed up the code. However, this is a bit tedious to do since lists must be correctly typed. Thus, it may not worth it.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I was so focused on vectorised solutions that I did not think to simply keep track of the slice index. This is the obvious solution, and very impressive! I feel bad I did not think of it myself. XD